# How to play video from dropbox into mediaelement of my win phone 8 app?

Tags: streaming, windows-phone-8, dropbox

I am creating an windows phone 8 app which browse and play content of dropbox with the help of rest api's.

Dropbox provide link to download file with some authorization headers. But I am not able to play that video into media element with that uri.

How can I play video into my app from dropbox(and sugarsync also).

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell which call you are using today but you should check out the [/media](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/api#media) call if you aren't already using it.